# Lock Perl sub routine

Tags: multithreading, perl, locking, flock

I wrote a CGI script. One of its subroutines can't be executed at the same time.  i.e. the same user (or hacker) run two instances at the exact same time). How can I avoid this?

I made the following work-around using lock files, but I'm not sure if it is safe:

```
unless (-e $filelock) {
    sub_that_should_be_locked();
}


sub sub_that_should_be_locked {
    open FILE, ">", $filelock;
    flock DATAFILE, LOCK_EX;
    close FILE;

    ...Code that cannot be executed at the same time...   
    ...Code that cannot be executed at the same time...

    unlink $filelock;
}
```

There should be no waiting/queue, concurrent processes should never call sub_that_should_be_locked

Comment: This is still susceptible to race conditions. If two threads both reach your `unless` line at the same time, then both will continue happily under the incorrect assumption that they are the only copy that is running.

Comment: @ikegami has said that you want *"to avoid calling `sub_that_should_be_locked` entirely"*. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, "sub_that_should_be_locked" should never run/be called at the same time 'cause it is a routine that gets a money balance and subtract all funds, if "sub_that_should_be_locked" run at the same time, the money balance would get negative instead of 0 as i desire.

Comment: We all know it shouldn't run at the same time in multiple processes. The question is: What should happen if two processes try to run it at the same time? Should the second process just skip calling `sub_that_should_be_locked`, or should the second process wait for the first process to exit `sub_that_should_be_locked`?

Comment: no waiting, the second process should skip calling `sub_that_should_be_locked` because a fraction of second could cause problems too as the balance may not update so quickly

Comment: Your requirement as stated can be met by simply removing all calls to `sub_that_should_be_locked`, but I doubt that that is what you want. Under what circumstances should the subroutine be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not safe. There's a race condition in your code since there's time between the `-e` and the `open`. Don't ever use `-e` with lock files.

Instead of checking if the file exists, check if the file is already locked. This is done using a non-blocking `flock`. It'll return success if the file isn't already locked, and it'll return error `EWOULDBLOCK` if the file is already locked.

Note that for this to work, you must hold the lock for the entire time `sub_that_should_be_locked` is executing. (Your code releases it as soon as it obtains it.)

```
use Fcntl qw( LOCK_EX LOCK_NB );

sub get_lock_nb {
   my ($qfn) = @_;

   open(my $fh, '+>:raw', $qfn)
      or die("Unable to open file \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   if (!flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
      return undef if $!{EWOULDBLOCK};
      die("Unable to lock file \"$qfn\": $!\n");
   }

   return $fh;
}

sub sub_that_should_be_locked {
   ... Mutually exclusive code ...
}

{
   my $lock = get_lock_nb("file.lock");
   sub_that_should_be_locked() if $lock;
}
```

Comment: PS - Note that I avoided using a global variable for the file handle (`open my $fh` instead of `open FILE`). Avoid using global variables whenever possible.

Comment: What is the final result? All concurrent callings to sub_that_should_be_locked would be rejected? All would be rejected but the first one? Or something else? i'm a bit confused, i'm familiar with perl but not with flock/linux internals

Comment: @user3518089, Like your code, the second process simply avoids calling `sub_that_should_be_locked` if a process is already executing it. Like you asked, it doesn't wait. If you a different result, let me know (by editing your questions and leaving a comment here saying you edited your question).

Comment: that's exactly it, i just hope it works cause i have no reliable means to test it :D

Comment: @user3518089, Put `sleep 15;` in `sub_that_should_be_locked`, and it should be easy to see what happens.

Comment: i'm testing the code with no concurrent processes and it dies at Unable to lock file "/tmp/file.lock": Invalid argument

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot to do `use Fcntl qw( LOCK_EX LOCK_NB );`. If so, that also means you forgot to do `use strict; use warnings;` (as you always should) since they would have caught that error sooner.

Comment: solved with `use Fcntl qw( LOCK_EX LOCK_NB ),` thank you very much

Comment: Added the `use Fcntl ...` to my answer. I figured you knew you needed it since your existing code already needed it.

Comment: What about `use strict; use warnings;`? Do add those. If you don't, many errors will be hidden from you.

Comment: It may be strange, but i only add those once the project is finished, so i  take a calm time to polish everything. By the way i tested the code with your suggestion of `sleep 15;` that proved the code works perfectly for what i needed.

Comment: @user3518089: Yes it's very strange. So you think of bug fixing as *polishing*? And your project is "finished" before you have found all of the bugs?

Comment: @user3518089, If you have no bugs, adding `use strict; use warnings;` doesn't do anything. I don't understand why you'd only want to find the bugs "after you're done" (which you're clearly not if there are still bugs).

Answer (score 1):

The threads that you want to synchronise shouldn't create and delete lock files.

You should ensure that the file exists *before* the threads are started, and then the subroutine should use a *lexical* file handle to open the lock file for *input*.

Like this

```
open my $lock_fh, '<', $lockfile or die $!;
flock $lock_fh, LOCK_EX;
```

as its first action. That will suspend the thread until it is nect in the queue, after which the file will be closed implicitly at the end of the subroutine (and so release its lock) because `$lock_fh` goes out of scope

Comment: This doesn't meet the OP's requirements since it blocks if someone else is holding the lock. // Also, expecting lock files to already exist is an unneeded restriction that prevents you from placing the lock files in `/tmp`

Comment: @ikegami: I hesitate to respond as you tend to lead a merry dance in your comment dialogues, but how is that contrary to the OP's statement?

Comment: He doesn't want to block if someone holds a lock; Instead, He wants to avoid calling `sub_that_should_be_locked` entirely. That was the purpose of the `-e` check, and he stated it explicitly as well.

Comment: @ikegami: I believe your solution should start by describing the problem that it is answering